# Find multiple solutions of a non-linear system with more variables that equations

Tags: equation-solving

I have a vector `P0inc` that depends on 7 variables that are `{tinc1, tinc2, tinc3, tinc4, tinc5, tinc6, tinc7}`. I would like to find let's say 20 solutions of the system `P0inc==P0temp`, knowing that `P0temp` is a known vector with numerical values. For this I am using `FindInstance` as shown below:

```
FindInstance[P0inc == P0temp, {tinc1, tinc2, tinc3, tinc4, tinc5, tinc6, tinc7}, Reals, 20];
```

However, it doesn't work: it takes forever to compile and never gives me any result.

---

I am using the following code, so that maybe this will help you understand the problem better:

**1.** In the 1st part in my code, I simply define some functions that will help me build the equation that I want to resolve easily:

```
Ti[i_, j_, b_, d_, a_, t0_, texp_] := ({{Cos[texp[[i, j]] + t0[[j]]], -Sin[texp[[i, j]] + t0[[j]]]*Cos[b[[j]]], Sin[texp[[i, j]] + t0[[j]]]*Sin[b[[j]]], a[[j]]*Cos[texp[[i, j]] + t0[[j]]]}, {Sin[texp[[i, j]] + t0[[j]]], Cos[texp[[i, j]] + t0[[j]]]*Cos[b[[j]]], -Cos[texp[[i, j]] + t0[[j]]]*Sin[b[[j]]], a[[j]]*Sin[texp[[i, j]] + t0[[j]]]}, {0, Sin[b[[j]]], Cos[b[[j]]], d[[j]]}, {0, 0, 0, 1}});
P[i_, b_, d_, a_, t0_, texp_, P7_] := Ti[i, 1, b, d, a, t0, texp].Ti[i, 2, b, d, a, t0, texp].Ti[i, 3, b, d, a, t0, texp].Ti[i, 4, b, d, a, t0, texp].Ti[i, 5, b, d, a, t0, texp].Ti[i, 6, b, d, a, t0, texp].Ti[i, 7, b, d, a, t0, texp].P7;
```

**2.** After this, I define the constant parameters of the vector `P`:

```
breal = {-90, 90, -90, -90, 90, -90, 0}*Pi/180;
dreal = {455, 0, 770, 0, -531, 0, -131};
areal = {0, -65, 0, -65, 0, -29, 0};
t0real = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}*Pi/180;
P7real = {0, 0, 50, 1};
```

**3.** So now, I generate random values for the variables of the vector P and then calculate `P0temp`:

```
tall = RandomReal[360, {1, 7}]*Pi/180;
P0temp = P[1, breal, dreal, areal, t0real, tall, P7real];
```

**4.** So now, P0temp is a know vector with numerical values that corresponds to the function `P[i_, b_, d_, a_, t0_, texp_, P7_]` when `texp==tall` (the others parameters were fixed in section **2.**.

**5.** Finally now, I define the 7 parameters `tinc` which are the variables of the equation I want to solve and I calculate the expression of the vector `P0inc` (which depends on `tinc`) and try to solve the equation:

```
tinc = Table[0, {i, 1, 1}, {j, 1, 7}];
tinc[[1, 1]] = tinc1;
tinc[[1, 2]] = tinc2;
tinc[[1, 3]] = tinc3;
tinc[[1, 4]] = tinc4;
tinc[[1, 5]] = tinc5;
tinc[[1, 6]] = tinc6;
tinc[[1, 7]] = tinc7;
P0inc = P[1, breal, dreal, areal, t0real, tinc, P7real];
FindInstance[P0inc == P0temp, {tinc1, tinc2, tinc3, tinc4, tinc5, tinc6, tinc7}, Reals, 20];
```

As I said the `FindInstance` does not give me any results. It should at least give me the solution `tinc==tall`, as `p0all` was calculated from `tall`.

If I change the vector equation `P0inc==P0temp` by `P0inc[[1]]==P0temp[[1]]` or `P0inc[[2]]==P0temp[[2]]` or `P0inc[[3]]==P0temp[[3]]`, it works! I also tried `Norm[P0inc-P0temp]==0`, it does not work!

Could you please test this program and see if it is working for you, and if not, any suggestions?

(PS: I am using Mathematica 10.2 and I am a beginner so my program is probably not optimized.)

Comment: Any answers?? any suggestions??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rewrote the code a fair bit to simplify working with it:

```
T[b_, d_, a_, t_] := {{Cos[t], -Cos[b] Sin[t], Sin[b] Sin[t], a Cos[t]}, 
                      {Sin[t], Cos[b] Cos[t], -Cos[t] Sin[b], a Sin[t]},
                      {0 b, Sin[b], Cos[b], d},
                      {0 b, 0 b, 0 b, ConstantArray[1, Length[b]]}};
P[b_, d_, a_, t_, p7_] := Fold[Dot, Transpose[T[b, d, a, t], {2, 3, 1}]].p7;
```

I rewrote `Ti` as `T` and wrote both `T` and `P` in a fashion that is more amenable to *Mathematica*'s automatic vectorization. In many cases, you don't need to pass indices: matrices of the same size can automatically be added and multiplied piecewise, and most mathematical functions from $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ are automatically expanded over a real vector's members. `Transpose` is used in `P` to rearrange the result to match the original specification. `Fold` is used to eliminate a lot of code repetition: `Fold[Dot, {a,b,c,d}] == a.b.c.d`, which for very long lists prevents a lot of needless typing and decreases the chance of making a typo. Furthermore, it will automatically expand for longer lists as needed.

```
(* tall=RandomReal[360,7]*Pi/180; *)
tall = {3.802585264448382`, 5.800064320152033`, 2.600209644180517`, 
   1.9888042059370301`, 3.4126484372045818`, 2.305359071351031`, 
   2.8964239600958592`};
breal = {-90, 90, -90, -90, 90, -90, 0}*Pi/180;
dreal = {455, 0, 770, 0, -531, 0, -131};
areal = {0, -65, 0, -65, 0, -29, 0};
t0real = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}*Pi/180;
P7real = {0, 0, 50, 1};
```

I chose a specific `tall` for replicability, and I replaced it with a single vector rather than a 1x7 matrix, to correspond with the cleanup performed in `P` and `T`.

```
P0temp = P[breal, dreal, areal, t0real + tall, P7real]
```

> {767.031, 284.856, 832.943, 1.}

Note that `t0real` and `tall` have been combined into one argument in `P`. This is intentional, and will also be useful later. They were never used individually in the original definition, regardless.

Let us now investigate `P0inc`. There's no need to assign the members of `tinc` individually, just give them spontaneously generated names:

```
P0inc = P[breal, dreal, areal, t0real + Table[tinc[i], {i, 1, 7}], P7real];
```

If you investigate the expression, it's a bit messy, but it has been expanded symbolically. The variables to find instances for are then `tinc[1]` through `tinc[7]`.

As you have noted though, `FindInstance` takes forever in this case. So does `Eliminate` and `Solve`, which are other common methods of handling this.

So instead, we'll consider an objective function instead, of the form `Norm[Rationalize[P0temp - P0inc, 0]]`. Since this function is defined by an underspecified system, hopefully all of its minima are zeros, and we can then use `FindMinimum` to find local minima rapidly from random starting points. We use `Rationalize` here because we need extended precision later.

```
randomsoln := Quiet@FindMinimum[Norm[Rationalize[P0temp - P0inc, 0]], 
  Table[{tinc[i], RandomReal[{-10, 10}]}, {i, 1, 7}], 
  WorkingPrecision -> 40];
```

This code manages that. Again we use `Table` to generate the solution variables rather than writing them all manually, along with random initial conditions for them. It turns out that `FindMinimum` needs added precision for this calculation to get a reasonably small number for the objective function, so I set `WorkingPrecision -> 40`. If you want closer matches and are willing to spend a bit of extra time, that can easily be increased. You can then extract a random solution by evaluating `randomsoln`. To extract 20 of them, perhaps try:

```
Table[randomsoln, {i, 1, 20}]
```

It's entirely possible some of them will lie on the same solution line, but it's likely that all of them will be different. If you're only interested in the variables, you can use `randomsoln[[2]]` to discard the objective function's evaluated value and only extract the actual variable values.

Also note that `tinc[7]` is actually independent of this system, and this method will choose it entirely randomly.

---

To constrain the solution variables to the interval of $-\pi$ to $\pi$, the simplest solution is to simply `Mod` the values to the right place. `P` is periodic in `tinc` on all dimensions with a period of $2\pi$, due to the trigonometric functions used in its construction. Thus, to transform the solution values appropriately, the following will suffice:

```
constrainsoln[s_] := {s[[1]], 
   s[[2]] /. (Rule[x_, y_] :> 
      Rule[x, Mod[y + π, 2 π] - π])};
```

This is used on the solutions found by `FindMinimum`, e.g.:

```
constrainsoln[randomsoln]
```

The reason why `FindMinimum`'s constraints don't always work well is because the edges of the solution space will have local minima, which `FindMinimum` makes no particular attempt to escape.

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution and for taking time to optimize the code and explaining the changes. It wroks!! finally!!
I have just one question:
I wanted to add constraints to the variables tinc, so I did so by :randomsoln := Quiet@FindMinimum[Norm[Rationalize[P0temp - P0inc, 0]], 
  Table[{tinc[i], RandomReal[{-Pi, Pi}], -Pi, Pi}, {i, 1, 7}], 
  WorkingPrecision -> 40];
It works, however, the objective function's evaluated value is not close to Zero, how can I solve this please? I tried to set AccuracyGoal -> 8, but it did not help.

Comment: Probably a result of local minima in the solution space. I'm not really sure there's a good way to resolve it, other than just discarding all of the values with poor solution values. `FindMinimum` isn't really a root-finding method, so it's not actually trying to get to 0. I just picked it because it's usually going to be fast. That said, because it's fairly fast, just re-picking solutions until you have enough might be an option for most value sets. I'll think about it though.

Comment: @Salma The function turns out to be periodic, so it's possible to transform arbitrary solutions to the requested solution space directly.